# Redirect parameter to its parent post url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have several set of error URL with parameter that i need to redirect to the parent post URL

```
    http://www.mysite.co/post1.html?amp=1
    http://www.mysite.co/post1.html?amp=0
    http://www.mysite.co/post1.html?utm_source=xxxxx
```

so what im trying to achieve `http://www.mysite.co/post1.html?amp=1 (status 404 )` should redirect to `http://www.mysite.co/post1.html (200 ok)`

i tried to add htaccess code but it always gave me 500 errors, can someone help me with the proper htaccess code

Htacess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END                 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

current permalinks are set to

```
/%postname%.html
```

Parameter in url `?amp`, `?utm_source` are added by third party service/plugins which resulted 404 error

Comment: Sure we like to help. But for that you need to add your current rewriting rules to your question. How else do you expect us to help fixing them without?

Comment: Also please be more clear about what you actually ask for... what do you mean by "parent post URL"? A URL is a URL, there is not such thing as a "get URL" and a "post URL". Get and post are methods of how a specific URL is requested. It is not different URLs.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: Thanks, but those rewriting rules have no trace of any attempt to rewrite according to what you explain in the question. There is no rewriting to `/post1.html` anywhere in there.

Comment: And another general hint: a http status 500 is just a generic statement. It does not name any details because you certainly do not want to tell everyone out there what is wrong exactly with your site. Instead you need to take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can read what the specific issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(amp=[01]|utm_source=[^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^[\w-]\.html$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

This matches any URL-path that ends in `.html`. Only the specific query strings as mentioned in the question are matched. ie. `amp=0` or `amp=1` or `utm_source=<something>`. It will not redirect `amp=2` or `utm_source=` or `utm_source=<something>&foo=1` etc.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) discards the original query string.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> #REDIRECTION UTM CLEAR
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> ```
>
> which one you thing serves better?

What do you mean by "better"?

As written, this code is strictly invalid (and contains superfluous directives). But (when corrected) this code arguably matches too much (and does not handle the `amp` URL parameter at all). It matches `utm` anywhere in the query string which could potentially create conflicts with existing code. It also matches any URL-path, so is potentially checking 1000s of requests that don't need checking. eg. It would match `/image.jpg?nutmeg=5` and `/?scoutmaster=1` - which clearly have nothing to do with `utm` tracking parameters (which all start `utm_`).

The code I posted above matches precisely the criteria you've stated in the question. And thus avoids potential conflicts. So, from that perspective, the code I posted above is "better".

However, to match `amp` or any URL parameter that simply starts `utm_` and only whole URL parameters that might occur anywhere in the query string then use something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(amp|utm_\w+)=
RewriteRule ^[\w-]\.html$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

This matches URLs of the form `/%postname%.html` - your permalink structure. It does not match `/image.jpg` etc.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. The `RewriteBase` directive is entirely superfluous. You should not wrap these directives in a `<IfModule>` container.

Note that if you have any legitimate URL parameters mixed in then they will also be removed.

This matches the following:

- `/<postname>.html?amp=<anything>`
- `/<postname>.html?utm_source=<anything>`
- `/<postname>.html?utm_campaign=<anything>&bar=1`
- `/<postname>.html?foo=1&utm_<something>=<anything>`
- etc.

But does not match:

- `/<postname>.html?wamp=<anything>`
- `/<postname>.html?nutmeg_source=<anything>`
- `/image.jpg?utm_source=<anything>`
- etc.

Comment: `#REDIRECTION UTM CLEAR
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  which one you thing serves better? it does redirecting to post url but i still watching my http.log in case it creating additional unused  url  [source] (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/301-redirection-removes-utm-tags-from-urls)

Comment: @BrittWell "better"? That code is strictly invalid and potentially matches too much. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @BrittWell If this helped answer your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer on the left below the voting arrows (to help other users and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). You can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: thank you mr white for your help ...i already click the button you mention twice..maybe i could only allowed to clicked it once

Comment: @BrittWell There are two "buttons". One is a _checkmark_ `✓` for "accepting" the answer and the other is an up arrow `▲` for "upvoting". If this answered your question and you found it informative then you should click both. You should only click each one once since it will "undo" the action if you click it again (just like a checkbox).